# QProcess received sigpipe signal

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I have this piece of code which use `QProcess` to grep output of some Linux command. Like this:

```
QString Info::getUsedHddSize(){
  QProcess hddUsedProcess;
  hddUsedProcess.start("bash");
  hddUsedProcess.waitForStarted(1000);
  hddUsedProcess.write("df -lh --total | grep total");
  hddUsedProcess.closeWriteChannel();
  hddUsedProcess.waitForFinished(1000);

  QString out =QString(hddUsedProcess.readAllStandardOutput()) ;
  return out;
}
```

This works fine if create the object, call the method within a function. Like this:

```
Info a;
QString result = a.getUsedHddSize();
```

But if I store `Info` as a variable within a class and use the method, it will eventually crash because it receives signal "SIGPIPE". I find this quite weird. Like this:
test.h

```
class Test{
...
private:
 Info info;
}
```

test.cpp

```
void Test::foo(){

 QString a = info.getUsedHddSize();// the program crash here with signal SIGPIPE.
}
```

A [quick search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=qprocess%20sigpipe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&ei=h9yzVLDOPOaJ8Qff9YDwBA) doesn't return anything works for me. And I don't want to ignore that signal.

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: How do you store it in the class and how to you initialize the `Info` class object?

Comment: Why would bash finish at all? ``waitForFinished()`` is for the first command of QProcess (``.start("bash")``). Try calling ``bash -c \"df -lh --total | grep total\"``.

Comment: @SebastianLange: thank for your suggestion, do you think that the critical point? That's the reason of the crash?

Comment: @vahancho: I update the question with the info you requested.